# Aurelia attached triggers before repeat.for

Tags: javascript, templates, aurelia

I'm trying to setup certain logic in Aurelia that would affect DOM nodes looped by repeat.for. If I understand the documentation correctly, the attached() callback of the view is called after DOM rendering and is the place put this kind of logic in.

The problem is that the attached() callback seems to be fired before the repeat.for binding is complete, leaving me with only a partially rendered dom.

In order to illustrate the problem:

I have a custom element containing:

```html
<template>
    <ul>
      <li repeat.for="thing of things"></li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Once attached is called(), I would expect having a rendered DOM containing all the li elements, instead. A simple dump of the dom shows an empty

How can is implement a callback that gets access to those li nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attached` is called when the component's DOM element is "attached" to the DOM.  There may be child components such as `repeat`ed templates that are further down in the queue to be rendered, the easiest thing to do would be to put your logic at the bottom of the queue:

```js
import {inject, TaskQueue} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(TaskQueue)
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(taskQueue) {
    this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
  }

  doSomethingAfterRepeatIsRendered() {
    // your logic...
  }

  attached() {
    this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask({
      call: () => this.doSomethingAfterRepeatIsRendered();
    });
  }
}
```

There are better approaches than this, but I would need to know more about what kind of work you need to do with the `<li>` elements to provide a better answer. It's uncommon to use the TaskQueue directly, often things can be refactored into custom elements or attributes that participate in the composition lifecycle more naturally. For example, if you need to do some jQuery stuff with your `<li>` elements, the "aurelia way" would be to separate this logic from your view-model using a custom attribute:

**do-something.js**

```js
import {inject, customAttribute} from 'aurelia-framework';
import $ from 'jquery';

@customAttribute('do-something')
@inject(Element)
export class DoSomethingCustomAttribute {
  constructor(element) {
    // "element" will be the DOM element rendered from the
    // template this attribute appears on, in this example an <li> element
    this.element = element;
  }    

  // now we don't need the task queue because attached is called when the 
  // <li> element is attached.
  attached() {
    // this.value is whatever the custom attribute is bound to, in this case
    // its a "thing" from your "things" array.
    $(this.element).doSomething(this.value);
  }
}
```

Here's the usage:

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./do-something"></require>

  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="thing of things" do-something.bind="thing"></li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Many thanks, implementing the taskQueue seems to be working. However, is it possible that queueMicroTask has a different behaviour than queueTask. (queueTask seems to work queueMicroTask not). I'm trying to some jQuery events on the li elements, if there are better ways to do this I' like know how.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer as well, this seems to work like a charm, good thing, because after my initial response about the working queue it stopped working. Empty queue gets injected? The custom attribute seems be a much better (working) solution.

Answer (score 2):

Would like to add here another option for catching DOM changes that is pretty simple, works not only for aurelia and could be really useful when you have some dynamic DOM changes triggered on user interaction, you can use `MutationObserver` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
import {DOM} from 'aurelia-pal';
...
let mutationObserver = DOM.createMutationObserver(() => {
   // handle dom changes here
});

//start to observe, note you can set different options
mutationObserver.observe(someDomElement, {childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true});
```

when you don't neet to observe anymore, you do `mutationObserver.disconnect();` usually from `detached()`