# Aurelia js dynamic select box and datepicker with materializecss

Tags: materialize, aurelia

Am using Aurelia Js and materializecss in my project. Here, I am creating a dynamic form and dynamic select box options. Problem is, materializecss works only when the page reloads(ctrl+R), if, i goes some other router and come back it not working. Seems like materializecss initiating issue also tried timeout for initiating. code below :

**Model:**

```
attached(){ $('select').material_select(); $('.datepicker').pickadate({
selectMonths: true, 
selectYears: 15 
}); }
this.httpValueConverter.call_http('index/list','POST',{})
        .then(data => {
            if(data.meta && data.meta.statusCode == 200) {
                this.index_lists = data.index.list;
            }
        });
```

**Response :**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"HR doc","createdTime":"2016-10-03T09:50:37.000Z","updatedTime":null},{"id":2,"name":"pay slips","createdTime":"2016-10-03T10:11:36.000Z","updatedTime":null}]
```

**Html :**

```
<div class="input-field col s6 hr_doc">
               <select value.bind="scanupload.indexId" ref="select_box">
 <option repeat.for="index of index_lists"
                                value.bind="index.id">${index.name}</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Index</label>
```

[image: on reload page, it loads select option]
[image: when, i comes form some other router, its not loading select options]

I guess, it should be the same solution for both issue. Help me out.

Comment: it seems to be a loading time issue. See if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037581/aurelia-attached-triggers-before-repeat-for

Comment: @FabioLuz tried taskQueue and `setTimeout( () => { this.load_index(); $('select').material_select();
}, 10);` , still its not fixed.

Comment: well, it's hard to say something without looking at the source-code. Try to reproduce your problem in a brand new project or in this gist https://gist.run/?id=b10264864c4a076b09572c1c41f5a8d6

Comment: You would need to refresh the select after the http call has finished. Unfortunately, Materialize select doesn't have a built-in refresh method. So you would need to destroy and initialize it. Like this:
$('select').material_select('destroy');
$('select').material_select();

Answer (score 1):

### Create custom elements

As Fabio mentioned, it's difficult to diagnose this without more source code or a working example. It seems to me that the problem has to do with timing and the page lifecycle. The typical solution involves creating custom elements.

**materialSelectCustomElement.js**

```
@inject(Element)
export class MaterialSelectCustomElement {

  @bindable items;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    $(this.element).material_select();
  }
}
```

**materialSelectCustomElement.html**

```
<template>
  <select value.bind="scanupload.indexId" ref="select_box">
    <option repeat.for="index of index_lists" value.bind="index.id">${index.name}</option>
  </select>
  <label>Index</label>
</template>
```

You can then use this in your code as a custom element:

**app.html**

```
<require from="materialSelectCustomElement"></require>
<material-select items.bind="selectableItems"></material-select>
```

This is not the best example because I'm not very familiar with materialize-css syntax. However, I've written up a very detailed blog on the process that I'd love for you to read: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/